# Jquery Dynamic Dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am very new to Jquery and am trying to open a dialog box for a series of links that open a dialog but im struggling to achieve this i have been searching for 3 days now but every post i find is from here and looks very technical with hardly any explanation.

My objective is to output rows from a database and have the row id assigned to buttons like so.

```
<div id="dialog">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<button id="opener" onClick="showDialog(1)">Oview details</button>
```

view details
  view details

I would like to be able to pass eventID from this to a Jquery Dialog box. 
So i tried encompassing the main dialog box code within a function and passing eventID as a parameter this didnt seem to work.

```
function showDialog(eventId)
{   
$(document).ready()
{
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: $(window).height() - 50,
            width: $(window).width() - 50,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 400,
            },

            hide: {
                effect: "explode",
                duration: 400
            },

            //pass the event Id to process and load the content into the div named content.
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $('#content').load("process.php?id=" eventId);
                ;

            }
            buttons: {
                            "Accept Event": function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            },
                            Cancel: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                           }

        });
        $("#opener").click(function () {
            //Show the div named dialog upon clicking of item id opener.
            $("#dialog").dialog('open');

        });
    });

}
}
```

I am able to achieve this in a simple confirm() Javascript box but really like the styles and effects of Jquery dialogs.

The page that im sending this information to is

process.php

```
    <?php 
print_r($_GET);
switch($_GET['id'])
{
    case 1: 
        echo "number 1 was passed to dialog"; 
        break;

    case 2: 
        echo "Number 2 was passed to dialog";
        break;

    default: 
        echo "Unknown Dialog Value!!";


}
```

Can anyone please explain the best way to achieve this in detail?

Many thanks to all those who take the time to read this truly long post.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's a bad idea to put the `document.ready` handler inside of a function. `$(document).ready() {` and `$(function () {` are the same thing too, so you have a `document.ready` handler inside of a `document.ready` handler, which is not necessary.

Rearrange your code to look like this:

```
$(document).ready() {
    function showDialog(eventId) {
        // Place your function logic here
        $("#dialog").dialog({...
    }
}
```

Also you want your click listener to be outside of the `showDialog` function, but inside the `document.ready`. The way you have it now, the handler will only be applied once `showDialog` has run, so you would have to click `#opener` twice to open the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and explaining why having those 2 lines are a bad idea.

Comment: I was unable to edit my post above but wanted to say thanks for the explanation about the click handler not firing until showDialog() has been activated.